# git cherry-pick commits in range where commit message contains string / matches regex?

Tags: git, branch, rebase, cherry-pick

### Background / scenario

I have a local work flow where

- I always commit on a "local" branch (ancestor of "master"), using commit messages beginning with issue number, such as "#123: Some message".
- I create feature branches which are also ancestors of "master".
- I then use rebase and/or cherry-pick to copy the commits from local onto the respective feature branch.

E.g. one way to do this:

```
git checkout local
git checkout -b 123-my-feature
git rebase -i master
```

In the interactive rebase editor, remove all commits where the message does not begin with #123.
This leaves a feature branch 123-my-feature which only contains commits from the issue #123.

Later, after the branch 123-my-feature already exists, subsequent commits on local also need to be picked / copied onto the 123-my-feature branch, if the message begins with #123. This is also possible with interactive rebase, or with individual cherry-picks. But the process is cumbersome.

### Question

Is there a way to do this with cherry-pick, and automatically filter by commit message?

E.g.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b 123-my-feature
git cherry-pick master..local --commit-message-begins-with="#123"
```

Or maybe even an interactive cherry-pick, where I can manually remove commits not beginning with "#123".

If there is another command which achieves this, why not. Doesn't have to be cherry-pick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not directly, no—but it's easy to write a script that would do it.

The general purpose command behind most other Git commands is [`git rev-list`, which has a huge option list](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html).  The first thing to know about `git rev-list`, though, is that it's actually almost the same command as `git log`.  They both take the same options, and do mostly the same things, except that `git rev-list` is aimed at producing hash IDs—mostly those of commits— for other Git programs, while `git log` is aimed at showing you, or some other human, the contents of commits.

Since `git log` has `--grep` which lets you select commits to show based on messages, `git rev-list` also has `--grep` which lets you select commits.  Using the pattern `'^#123: '`, for instance, would select commits whose log message has a line that starts with `123:`  (including a trailing space—choose your pattern here and use `git log` to test it).

Like `git log`, `git rev-list` will work backwards from whatever starting (or ending?) point you give it, and keep going forever, unless you tell it where to *stop* searching too.  You need to pick a stop-point; usually this would be a branch name, or tag, or perhaps even a raw hash ID, to select a commit where Git should terminate its backwards search for commits.  In this case, that stopping point might be `master`.  The general syntax for this is just what you wrote: `master..local` (or equivalently, `local ^master`).  Hence the list of commits you want is that generated by:

```
git rev-list --grep=... master..local
```

(try running this, or—even better—run `git log` first, and then run `git rev-list` and observe the difference).

Now, there's one or two remaining issues.  The first is that like `git log`, and pretty much most of Git, `git rev-list` works backwards, starting from the newest commits and going back in time.  But when you are cherry-picking, you tend to have to start at the earliest point in time and work forwards.  Fortunately `git log` has `--reverse`, so `git rev-list` also has `--reverse`.

The last obvious issue is that it's possible that `git rev-list` might find no commits.  In this case, you can let `git cherry-pick` itself complain, or you can check and do your own complaint.  To just let `git cherry-pick` complain:

```
git checkout -b 123-my-feature master
git cherry-pick $(git rev-list --reverse --grep '^#123' master..local)
```

(I've combined the branch-creation of `123-my-feature` with the setting of its initial value, to point to the same commit as `master`, so that the whole thing is just two lines of shell script.  To do this in a fancier way, you might capture the `git rev-list` output first, and only create the branch and run the cherry-pick if the list is not empty.)

Answer (score 3):

`GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` isn't very well known, it's mentioned exactly once in the docs (in the git config page, for `sequence.editor`) but it's exactly what you're looking for.

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR='sed -i /^pick [^ ]* #123 /!d' git rebase -i master
```

should do ya.

Comment: I'd use this method if it's a relatively rare task and there are few commits to drop from the rebase, and probably write a short script using `git rev-list` (a la my own answer) if it's a frequent task and there are few commits to cherry-pick out of long chains of commits. But this is definitely a nice way to do it (and upvoted).